Convolution theorem: proof via integral of Fourier transforms
Given two functions $f$ and $g$, their convolution is defined by:
$$
(f \ast g) (t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(t-x) dx \tag{1}\label{conv}
$$
The convolution theorem states that:
$$
F(f \ast g) (s) = F(f)(s) \cdot F(g)(s) \tag{2}\label{ft}
$$
This is usually proven by:

Apply the Fourier transform to $\eqref{conv}$:
$F(f \ast g) (s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2 \pi i s t} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(t-x) dx \right) dt$

Change the order of integration:
$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t-x) e^{-2 \pi i s t} dt \right) dx$

Perform a change of variables $u = t-x$:
$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-2 \pi i s x} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(u) e^{-2 \pi i s u} du \right) dx = F(f)(s) \cdot F(g)(s)$


However, I'm seeking another angle. Imagine that the products $f(x)g(y)$ are laid out on a 2D grid. Then setting $x=x$, $y=t-x$, equation \eqref{conv} can be viewed as integrating through one of the dashed lines (defined by $t$) in this picture:

Visually, we can see that this operation on the dashed lines is equivalent to "summing up" the solid lines. Then the proof proceeds by taking the Fourier transform on this "collapsed" line.
Now, due to the linearity of the Fourier transform, it feels like there should be another way: instead of summing up the solid lines first, and then taking the Fourier transform, do it the opposite way: first take the Fourier transform of the solid lines and then sum them up.
To do this, we need to be careful how we define our solid lines. In particular, we need to ensure that we're traversing it with the same pace as we do when integrating through $t$ in the conventional proof. To do this we can define the solid line as:
$$
l(t, \triangle) = f \left( \frac{t}{2} + \frac{\triangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right) g \left( -\frac{t}{2} + \frac{\triangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right)
$$
EDIT: This formulation of $l(t, \triangle)$ (and therefore the rest of the derivation) is wrong. See my answer below for the correct formulation.
This definition aims to ensure that coordinate $\triangle$ on the "collapsed" line (generated by summing the solid lines) will be the sum of the $l(t, \triangle)$ coordinates i.e.  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} l(t, \triangle) \space dt$. The $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ factor is to account for the fact that if we want to move length of $\triangle$ on the solid line, then we need to move $\frac{\triangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ in the $x$ and $y$ direction of the plane due to Pythagoras.
Now we need one additional consideration. When in the conventional proof, we're integrating through $t$, we're essentially deciding which points of the solid lines to pick. Again due to Pythogaras, changing t by some $\triangle_{t}$ will result in a displacement of $\frac{\triangle_{t}}{\sqrt{2}}$ on the solid line. To account for this, we need to define a new function:
$$
m(t, y) = l \left( t, \frac{y}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = f \left( \frac{t}{2} + \frac{y}{{2}} \right) g \left( -\frac{t}{2} + \frac{y}{{2}} \right)
$$
Taking the Fourier transform of $m(y)$, we get:
$$
F( m(t, y) )(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f \left( \frac{t}{2} + \frac{y}{{2}} \right) g \left( -\frac{t}{2} + \frac{y}{{2}} \right) e^{-2 \pi i s y} dy
$$
Integrate over $t$ to add up the many Fourier transforms:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F( m(t, y) )(s) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f \left( \frac{t}{2} + \frac{y}{{2}} \right) g \left( -\frac{t}{2} + \frac{y}{{2}} \right) e^{-2 \pi i s y} \space dy \space dt \tag{3}\label{conv2}
$$
Now we can perform a change of variables:
$$
u = -\frac{t}{2} + \frac{y}{2}
$$
$$
v = \frac{t}{2} + \frac{y}{2}
$$
Then:
$$
t = v - u
$$
$$
y = v + u
$$
The Jacobian matrix $J$ is:
$$
J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The determinant of $J$ is calculated as:
$$
\det(J) = \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) = -\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} = -\frac{1}{2}
$$
So we have:
$$
dt\,dy = |-\frac{1}{2}| du\,dv = \frac{1}{2} du\,dv
$$
Plugging this into \eqref{conv2}, we get:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f \left( \frac{t}{2} + \frac{y}{{2}} \right) g \left( -\frac{t}{2} + \frac{y}{{2}} \right) e^{-2 \pi i s y} \space dy \space dt
$$
$$
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f \left( v \right) g \left( u \right) e^{-2 \pi i s (v + u)} \frac{1}{2} \space dv \space du
$$
Since $e^{-2 \pi i s (v + u)} = e^{-2 \pi i s v} e^{-2 \pi i s u}$, we can separate the integrals:
$$
= \frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(v) e^{-2 \pi i s v} \,dv \right) \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(u) e^{-2 \pi i s u} \,du \right)
$$
Which are the Fourier transforms of $f$ and $g$, respectively:
$$
= \frac{1}{2} F(f)(s) \cdot F(g)(s)
$$
Now all is good apart from that pesky factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ at the start of the expression. This arose as part of changing variables, which I'm not sure whether it's correct. Any idea how to deal with this factor of $\frac{1}{2}$?

I messed up the solid line equation $l(t, \triangle)$ in my question. Instead of $f \left( \frac{t}{2} + \frac{\triangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right) g \left( -\frac{t}{2} + \frac{\triangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$, it should just be:
$$
f \left( t + \frac{\triangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right) g \left( -t + \frac{\triangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right)
$$
The usage of the variable $t$ here is also confusing because this $t$ actually plays a different role than $t$ in the definition of convolution (equation 1 of my question). Originally $t$ meant displacement of the dashed line from the origin. Here, instead of $t$, what we need is a variable expressing the displacement of the solid line from the origin. Let's call this $d$. So renaming the variable, we have:
$$
l \left( d, \triangle \right) = f \left( d + \frac{\triangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right) g \left( -d + \frac{\triangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right)
$$
Notice that the only thing that actually changed is the absence of the $\frac{1}{2}$ multiplicative factor next to $d$. The justification is that we should think of $d$ as one of the axis of integration for the solid line coordinate system. This axis is perpendicular to the solid line that intersects the origin. The other axis is the solid line itself intersecting the origin:

So when integrating through the horizontal $x$ axis in the conventional proof, for every $\delta_x$ move on the $(x + \delta_x, t - (x + \delta_x))$ line, we should also move $\delta_x$ (not $\frac{\delta_x}{2}$) on the diagonal $d$ axis in the new setup.
To calculate the Fourier transform of a single solid line, integrating by the $\triangle$ axis still requires special attention. As the integral in the conventional proof sweeps through the vertical $t$ axis, this corresponds to a diagonal move on the solid line. For every $\delta_t$ move on the $t$ axis, we move $\frac{\delta_t}{\sqrt{2}}$ on the $\triangle$ axis:

So we need a function $m(d, \triangle)$ that describes points on the solid lines and allows for traversal at the right pace. For every $\triangle$ increment, it should displace the point on the solid line by $\frac{\triangle}{\sqrt{2}}$:
$$
m \left( d, \triangle \right) = l \left( d, \frac{\triangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = f \left( d + \frac{\triangle}{2} \right) g \left( -d + \frac{\triangle}{2} \right)
$$
Now we can take the Fourier transform of this by $\triangle$ and integrate through $d$ to sum up the Fourier transforms:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F \left( m \left( d, \triangle \right) \right) (s) \space dd
$$
$$
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f \left( d + \frac{\triangle}{2} \right) g \left( -d + \frac{\triangle}{2} \right) e^{-2 \pi i s \triangle} \space d \triangle \space dd \label{convnew}\tag{1}
$$
Now we can make a change of variables:
$$
u = d + \frac{\triangle}{2}
$$
$$
v = -d + \frac{\triangle}{2}
$$
Then:
$$
\triangle = u + v
$$
$$
d = \frac{u - v}{2}
$$
The Jacobian is:
$$
J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial d}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial d}{\partial v} \\
\frac{\partial \triangle}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial \triangle}{\partial v}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The determinant:
$$
\text{det}(J) = \left(1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right) - \left(-1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1
$$
This implies:
$$
d \triangle \space dd = du \space dv
$$
Now plugging into $\eqref{convnew}$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f \left( u \right) g \left( v \right) e^{-2 \pi i s (u + v)} \space du \space dv
$$
Since $e^{-2 \pi i s (v + u)} = e^{-2 \pi i s v} e^{-2 \pi i s u}$, we can separate the integrals:
$$
= \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u) e^{-2 \pi i s u} \,du \right) \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(v) e^{-2 \pi i s v} \,dv \right)
$$
Which are the Fourier transforms of $f$ and $g$, respectively:
$$
= F(f)(s) \cdot F(g)(s)
$$
